# SQL - remainder / not belonging

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, where-clause

I am running a SQL query with a while constraint containing some "id's".
For example:

```
SELECT table.id
FROM TableOne table
WHERE table.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
AND some conditions
```

The query might return [1, 2] granted that some conditions are met. How would I go about returning [3, 4], that is, all the id's that have not met the conditions but are still part of the list in which I want to include?

Thanks

Comment: are you using sql server or mysql?

Comment: Please show us sample output.  Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is how you get result of ID you want to include and meet condition

```
SELECT table.id
FROM TableOne table
WHERE table.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
AND some conditions
```

Then, this is how to get result of ID you want to include but not meet condition

```
SELECT table.id
FROM TableOne table
WHERE table.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
AND NOT (some conditions)
```

Comment: I thought this is what OP required as well however this might not be entirely correct. What if id `3` is not in the table. If OP wants to show it as an output still, your solution is not correct. if he doesn't, then your solution is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a table with list of your ids and then do a `EXCEPT` from your query.

```
SELECT ID FROM
(
SELECT 1 ID
UNION ALL SELECT 2 
UNION ALL SELECT 3 
UNION ALL SELECT 4
)List
EXCEPT
SELECT table.id
FROM TableOne table
WHERE table.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
AND some conditions
```

***Assumption:*** If your table does not contain the ID listed in the query, the query below will still return that id.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT table.id
FROM TableOne table
WHERE table.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
AND NOT some conditions
```

it should return your result